# Differences between two CDFs

Tags: probability

```
Is it possible to obtain the CDF of differences between two CDFs?

What do I obtain if I subtract two CDFs?
```

I'd like to obtain the differences between two variables expressed in the same units, each one with a given CDF, and I thought of doing this by subtracting the cdf of each variable to obtain the cdf of the differences. Is this reasoning valid?

I've done this but the "CDF" I got sometimes decreases, i.e. for a given probability I get a smaller value for the difference between the two variables, so it is not really a CDF. Although I could reorder the results to make it become a CDF. Thanks

**EDIT:**
The two variables are output results from the same process using different values for input variables.

*Example*:

```
x = rnorm(50); y = rnorm(50)
xCDF = ecdf(x); yCDF = ecdf(y) 
plot(xCDF)
lines(yCDF)
F = function(z) xCDF(z)-yCDF(z)
plot(seq(-2,2,by=0.02), F(seq(-2,2,by=0.02)) ,type="l")
```

What does the last plot mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you have the CDFs $F_A$ and $F_B$ of two variables $A$ and $B$ and wish to find the CDF of $C=A-B$, then you have to do an integral over the two CDFs; in particular, suppose we want the probability that $C\leq 0$. This is, equivalently, the probability that $A\leq B$, so we can write
$$P(C\leq 0)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_A'(c+x)F_B'(x) dx\,dc$$
noting that the derivative of the CDFs are the PDFs. The integral runs over possible values of $c\leq 0$ and then all pairs $A=c+x$ and $B=x$ such that $A-B=c$. In general
$$P(C\leq k)=\int_{-\infty}^{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_A'(c+x)F_B'(x) dx \,dc.$$

Ultimately, this will probably be more painful than what you were doing, but it will be correct.

---

For some intuition about this, consider if you had discrete variables; suppose $A$ and $B$ were either $0$ or $1$ with probabilities $A_0$ and $A_1$, $B_0$ and $B_1$. Then, we could make a table of every possibility, along with the probability of it occurring
$$\begin{array}  .&& A=0 && A=1 \\ B=0 && A_0B_0 && A_1B_0 \\ B=1 && A_0B_1 && A_1B_1 \end{array}$$
then, the probability that $A-B$ is the sum of a diagonal on the table running top left to bottom right; so $P(A-B=-1)=A_0B_1$, $P(A-B=0)=A_0B_0+A_1B_1$, and $P(A-B=1)=A_1B_0$. The integral essentially runs over the set of values for which $A-B$ is constant and represents the sum you see above, and the product is the probability that both events occur. Perhaps more clearly, if $F_C$ is the CDF of $C$, then
$$F_C'(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_A'(x+c)F_B'(c)dc$$
and the CDF, as above, is just the integral of that.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I'd like to have all possible C values (which I do not know in advance). Plus, I don't know how to that integral. Does it not require that I know `C` in advance?

Comment: Why not do `F′A(c+x) - F′B(x)`?

Comment: I edited the answer to possibly elucidate things; no, you don't have to know C in advance, but the algebra to find it is tricky; what you want to do is substitute for F'A and F'B and try to solve it. However, if you are using normal distributions, it turns out that the difference of normal distributions is a normal distribution - check this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html

Comment: I could do it also by: estimating the kernel density of each histogram of A and B, and then generate samples of each kernel. Select one value of kernel A, a, and find differences a - samples of kernel B. Do this for sufficient number of values of kernel A and I should get the histogram of the differences and based on this find the ecdf. Is this also OK?