# Is the difference between the CDFs of two variables the same after addition of third variable to both?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have three independent random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ with CDFs $F_X(x)$, $F_Y(y)$ and $F_Z(z)$? Is it the case that
$F_{X+Z}(x+z)-F_{Y+Z}(y+z)=F_X(x)-F_Y(y)$?

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947642/differences-between-two-cdfs) provides a starting block but unsure how to proceed. For example, if $u=x+z$ and $v=y+z$ one could show (I think)
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[F_X(u-z)-F_Y(v-z)]f_Z(z)dz = F_X(x)-F_Y(y)$ or not equals to if that were the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The LHS is depending on $z$. The RHS is not.

E.g. have a look at what happens if the equality holds and $z\to\infty$. Then you end up with: $$1-1=F_X(x)-F_Y(y)$$

This cannot be true for every pair $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: What if the dependence on $z$ is only superficial, like in $(x+z)-(y+z)$?

Comment: @AlexM. It is not. E.g. let $z\to\infty$. Then the LHS tends to $1-1=0$. This shows that the equality can only hold if $F_X(x)=F_Y(y)$

Comment: Be so kind to explain your downvote.

Comment: Removed my downvote (and reversed it). Before the edit, the answer was technically true, but giving little insight as to why... and how to check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Out of interest is it possible to examine analytically whether it is approximately true for smaller values of z?

Comment: Moody stuff I think, and my view on it is very narrow. You could start by taking a look at degenerated $X,Y,Z$ taking constant values. They are automatically independent. This just to see what happens. I have no proper answer, but my intuition is somewhat distrusting.